# FileSharing Open, Edit and Save Only from mounted drive via localhost asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, copy-paste, file-sharing, save-as

I need to create an ASP.NET application which can open files from a mounted drive or folder on  Windows Server. These file directory structure should be viewed by accessing the `server-url` in IE or Chrome, etc.

The files should not be allowed to copy but should be able to opened by a locally installed app for editing and the saved to the same location. "Save As" option should be disabled

Please let me know your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has loaded the data into a local application, there's nothing you can do to prevent the user from saving it to a different file on their computer.